# Virtual Template Workarounds

Tags: c++, oop, templates, inheritance, virtual

I have a template container class that I derive from called `MyContainer`.  `MyContainer` defines methods like `Get()`, `Set()`, etc. to access individual elements.  I'd like to make a bitfield class implemented as a `MyContainer<char>`, where each `char` element holds `CHAR_BIT` number of bits.  However, to allow the user to operate on individual bits rather than entire bytes, I would have to make `Get()` and `Set()` virtual, which is illegal.  What are some alternatives?

I was thinking of defining `GetBit()` and `SetBit()` in the derived class, but this would violate the Liskov substitution principle.  (Think of a `SortMyContainer()` function.)

EDIT: Here is a simplified example:

```
template <typename Datatype>
struct MyContainer
{
    virtual Datatype Get();
};

template <typename Datatype> // Error: Templates may not be virtual.
virtual Datatype MyContainer<Datatype>::Get() // EDIT: The problem was on this line.  The "virtual" keyword should only appear with the function declaration.
{
    // ...
}
```

Comment: May I preach the NVI pattern or Template Method to you? See http://www.gotw.ca/publications/mill18.htm . The STL is often implemented after that principle.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is not illegal, only template virtual member functions are.

```
// valid
template<typename T> class MyContainer {
    virtual void set(const T &) = 0;
}

// not valid
class MyContainer {
    template <typename T> virtual void set (const T &) = 0;
}
```

If I got you wrong, please consider placing a code-sample.

*edit after your adding of example code:*

```
template <typename Datatype>
virtual // <-- nope, not here
Datatype MyContainer<Datatype>::Get()
{
    // ...
}
```

`virtual` is only part of the declaration inside the class body. This should be valid:

```
template <typename Datatype>
Datatype MyContainer<Datatype>::Get()
{
    // ...
}
```

However, note that the definition must be visible at the point of template instantiation. So either put it in the header-file, too (or in an extra-header that you then include into your real header), or leave it in the class-body.

*(please nobody mention `export`ed templates now, you and I know them a lot, but they are not quite a beginner topic, and deprecated with the next standard)*

Comment: The member functions are templates, though; they use the class's template parameter in return values and parameters.

Comment: @Maxpm: That's irrelevant. If they do not, themselves, have template parameters, then they are not templates.

Comment: @phresnel @DeadMG I've added a simplified example to the OP.

Comment: @Maxpm: If your compiler is rejecting that code, then it's *wrong*. Oh, apart from the fact that you're not supposed to put `virtual` there.

Comment: @DeadMG: Sometimes, compilers are wrong, especially very dated ones. @Maxpm: As DeadMG pointes out, when out-defining member functions, virtual must be omitted. It is only part of the declaration inside the class body.

Answer (score 3):

You appear to be confused about what constitutes a template. Class templates may have virtual functions, and indeed, those template parameters may appear in those function's signatures.

```
template<typename T> class an_interface {
    virtual T Get() = 0;
};
class a_class : public an_interface<int> {
};
```

This is perfectly valid. What's not perfectly valid is

```
class an_interface {
    template<typename T> virtual T Get() = 0;
}
```

Unless the specific member function in question has it's own, separate template parameters, the member function is not a template and may be virtual, irrespective of if it was generated from a class template.